# Notice: Array to string conversion when using Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I'm busy on this system to change your password, when the password is changed, a green box appears with the message 'Your password has been changed.'

When there's an error, a red box appears with the error, for example: 
"Your current password is incorrect", or "Your new password and the verification password aren't the same.".

So when there's a post request, I `count` the errors, if there's more then 0, return the errors like this:

```
public function nieuwpw($username, $currentpass, $newpass, $newpassconf)
{
    $this->errors[] = array();
    $this->succes[] = array();
    $query = $this->db->conn->prepare('SELECT pass FROM ht_users WHERE naam = ?');
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($dbpass);
    $query->store_result();
    while ($query->fetch()) {
        if (password_verify($currentpass, $dbpass))
        {
            if ($newpass === $newpassconf)
            {
                $newpasshash = password_hash($newpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $stmt = $this->db->conn->prepare('UPDATE ht_users SET pass = ? WHERE naam = ?');
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $newpasshash, $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
                else
            {
                $this->errors[] = 'Whoops, je 2 nieuwe wachtwoorden zijn niet gelijk.';
            }
        }
            else
        {
            $this->errors[] = 'Whoops, je huidige wachtwoord klopt niet!';
        }
    }
    if (count($this->errors) > 0)
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
    $this->succes[] = 'Je wachtwoord is met success gewijzigd!';
    return $this->succes;
    $query->close();
}
```

}

Thats the function I use to change passwords. The following is how I 'echo' the errors:

```
        <?php //24
//25
if(isset($users->succes))//26
{//27
    if (count($users->succes) > 0) //28
    {//29
        foreach ($users->succes as $succes) {//30
                    $content = '<div id="message_succes" style="background-color:#00B200; width:100%; height:30px;"><p style="color:#fff; font-family:Ubuntu; padding:5px;">' . $succes. '</p></div>';//31
    echo $content;//32
//33
            }   //34
    }//35
}//36
if(isset($users->errors))//37
{//38
    if (count($users->errors) > 0) //39
    {//40
        foreach ($users->errors as $errors) {//41
                    $content = '<div id="message_succes" style="background-color:#ff0033; width:100%; height:30px;"><p style="color:#fff; font-family:Ubuntu; padding:5px;">' . $errors. '</p></div>';//42
    echo $content;//43
//44
            }   //45
    }//46
}//47
//48
?> //49
```

And still, even tho I only echo the errors, or the success message, if there's more then 1, I get these errors:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\page16.php on line 31


Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\page16.php on line 42
```

In the second code block, I numbered the lines so you can see which lines throw the errors.

When doing a `var_dump`, I get the following output:

`array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(41) "Whoops, je huidige wachtwoord klopt niet!" }`

Also, what I find really weird is that it shows the red error box twice, and even tho there isn't any success message, it also shows the green box...

I hope that this'll be considered a complete question and someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of the error is in line 3 and 4 of the first code block you posted:

```
$this->errors[] = array();
$this->succes[] = array();
```

Try changing those lines into:

```
$this->errors = array();
$this->succes = array();
```

In your code you create an array and immediately set the first element of the array to be an array. You can see that in the var_dump you posted:

array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(41) "Whoops, je huidige wachtwoord klopt niet!" }

Later on, when you loop over either the $errors or $succes array, the first iteration of the loop gives you back the array you set as the first element of the $errors or $succes array. Then you try to echo that array and php gives you a notice that you are echoing an array.

Does my suggested fix work and do you see why your code breaks?

PS:

1. Try to keep all your code in English so it's easier for non-Dutch speaking persons to understand your code.
2. The following string is written in Dutch: 'Je wachtwoord is met success gewijzigd!'. In Dutch, 'succes' is written with 1 's', so it should be ''Je wachtwoord is met succes gewijzigd!'.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using it like this ??

```
$this->errors = array();
$this->succes = array();
```

and

```
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if(isset($user->succes))
        {
            $content = '<div id="message_succes" style="background-color:#00B200; width:100%; height:30px;"><p style="color:#fff; font-family:Ubuntu; padding:5px;">' .$user->succes. '</p></div>';
            echo $content;

        }  
        if(isset($user->errors))
        {
            $content = '<div id="message_succes" style="background-color:#ff0033; width:100%; height:30px;"><p style="color:#fff; font-family:Ubuntu; padding:5px;">' . $user->errors. '</p></div>';
            echo $content;

        }   
    }
```

comment if any errors...